# Visual Studio - can't build anything

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I worked arround with visual studio and cordova every thing was fine but suddenly when i want to build the app for iOS (doesn't matter if ripple or remote device) after a abouut two seconds I get the following error message.

It really appeared from one to another second... I did nothing special.
Also when i create a blank project it doesn't work - same issue!

> Error - Cannot load global packages. System.AggregateException:
>   Mindestens ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. --->
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json at
>   'C:\Users\m.hüttl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json':
>   Error reading package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may
>   contain objects with duplicate properties.
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. --->
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may contain objects
>   with duplicate properties.
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. ---> System.ArgumentException: Can not
>   add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.
>   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.ValidateToken(JToken o, JToken
>   existing)    bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.InsertItem(Int32
>   index, JToken item, Boolean skipParentCheck)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.InsertItem(Int32 index, JToken item,
>   Boolean skipParentCheck)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal(Int32 index, Object
>   content, Boolean skipParentCheck)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.Add(Object content)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.AddValue(JValue value, JsonToken
>   token)    bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.WriteNull()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteClose(JsonContainerType type)
>   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEndObject()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd(JsonContainerType type)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteAll()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.Close()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateJObject(JsonReader
>   reader)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.ReaderPackageJsonSource..ctor(TextReader
>   reader)    --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.ReaderPackageJsonSource..ctor(TextReader
>   reader)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullPathToFile)    --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
>   bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource.WrapExceptionAndRethrow(String
>   fullPathToFile, Exception ex)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullPathToFile)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.DirectoryPackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullDirectoryPath)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NpmController.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
>   ---> (Interne Ausnahme #0) Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json at
>   'C:\Users\m.hüttl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json':
>   Error reading package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may
>   contain objects with duplicate properties.
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. --->
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may contain objects
>   with duplicate properties.
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. ---> System.ArgumentException: Can not
>   add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.
>   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.ValidateToken(JToken o, JToken
>   existing)    bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.InsertItem(Int32
>   index, JToken item, Boolean skipParentCheck)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.InsertItem(Int32 index, JToken item,
>   Boolean skipParentCheck)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal(Int32 index, Object
>   content, Boolean skipParentCheck)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.Add(Object content)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.AddValue(JValue value, JsonToken
>   token)    bei Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.WriteNull()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteClose(JsonContainerType type)
>   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEndObject()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd(JsonContainerType type)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteAll()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.Close()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateJObject(JsonReader
>   reader)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    bei
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.ReaderPackageJsonSource..ctor(TextReader
>   reader)    --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.ReaderPackageJsonSource..ctor(TextReader
>   reader)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullPathToFile)    --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
>   bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource.WrapExceptionAndRethrow(String
>   fullPathToFile, Exception ex)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullPathToFile)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.DirectoryPackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullDirectoryPath)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   bei
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NpmController.d__1.MoveNext()<---

Comment: _"Error reading package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may contain objects with duplicate properties."_ - I'd review the `package.json` file that the error is referring to. Consider running it through [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to see if you get any errors.

Comment: It seems like you have a corrupted `package.json`. Have you tried deleting the file and repopulating?

Comment: deleting package.json worked to get rid of this error for me.